# Express.js parsing form body

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

There is the following form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <% include menu %>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Fill in the form below to add a new post.</p>
    <% include messages %>
    <form action='/post' method='post'>
      <p>
        <input type='text' name='entry[title]' placeholder='Title' />
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea name='entry[body]' placeholder='Body'></textarea>
      </p> 
      <p>
        <input type='submit' value='Post' />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Express.js code part:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({secret: 'SomeSecretKey'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

But when I post this form I get the following json response (through `res.json({body: req.body})`)

```
{"body":{"entry[title]":"111","entry[body]":"222"}}
```

And I can't use req.body.entry.title (Error: Can't get title of undefined). How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`extended`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended) to `true` and the `qs` module will instead be used to parse the body, which supports nesting.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the latest version of Node in Action is but a lot of the exercises I found to be outdated, just to be mindful of.

If you want a really quick fix just drop the entry[ ]. So make the names title and body and then you will get...

```
{"body":{title:"111",body:"222"}}
```